# WordPress query results where all columns have the same value as column of selected id

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have looked at various results but I am not sure how to make it work. All the examples have different tables to select or the same value based on selected column value.

But I need a different solution, I have an id of the selected item and based on that id I need to get value from column and list all other rows that have the same value as that column of selected id.

```
+----+------------------------------+------------+
| id |             name             | country_id |
+----+------------------------------+------------+
| 1  | Andaman and Nicobar Islands  |        101 |
| 2  | Andhra Pradesh               |         95 |
| 3  | Arunachal Pradesh            |        101 |
| 4  | Assam                        |        101 |
| 5  | Bihar                        |         43 |
+----+------------------------------+------------+
```

So if I have posted `$_POST` state with id `3` I need to somehow get that state `country_id` and display all other states with the same `country_id` so the final list would be

```
+----+------------------------------+------------+
| id |             name             | country_id |
+----+------------------------------+------------+
| 1  | Andaman and Nicobar Islands  |        101 |
| 3  | Arunachal Pradesh            |        101 |
| 4  | Assam                        |        101 |
+----+------------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should do, assuming that `id` is a unique value

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table`
WHERE `country_id`=(SELECT `country_id` FROM `your_table` WHERE `id`='your_id')
```

Comment: yes the id is unique value as i showed in the table example but the code is not working.

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević what exactly is not working? Any errors ?

Comment: I am not sure, the page when come to that function it just dies. I am not so familiar with custom queries on wordpress so i am reading on $wpdb query now and will try to debug it.

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević add the code you have now and show errors you're getting